# Configuring Weblogic Credentials dynamically

Tags: spring-security, jms, apache-camel, weblogic12c

I am trying to connect to a Weblogic queue from camel through spring DSL.Everything works fine when i hardcode the credentials inside spring beans. What i want now is to populate these credentials dynamically for security reasons rather than having them exposed in spring/camel context. How could i acheive this?Help is appreciated

Comment: As of WebLogic 11g, security information is stored in a thread-local of WebLogic. This doesn't work well with Spring's JMS message listener container and you may encouter several issues: http://www.jayway.com/2011/06/26/secure-jms-spring-and-weblogic-a-one-click-workaround/ http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Weblogic-JMS-Security-Issues-A-possible-resolution-td5735108.html

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the connection factory for the JMS component by using a Spring FactoryBean Java code, but I'm not sure if that is what you want.